# I'm facing a problem with cap sense proximity

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, arduino-ide, library

I've made use of the cap sense library in Arduino to make a touch less piano. I went according to my design and tried it out. Even after using a 10M ohm resistor, my program is only responding when I'm touching the electrodes. I want it to start detecting my finger from at least a few inches away.

I've posted the schematic and code for Arduino and Processing below.

[image]

Code for processing:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import processing.serial.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer song40;
AudioPlayer song41;
AudioPlayer song42;
AudioPlayer song43;
AudioPlayer song44;
AudioPlayer song45;
AudioPlayer song46;
AudioPlayer song47;
AudioPlayer song48;
AudioPlayer song49;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;     // Data received from the serial port

int r=0;
int m=1;
void setup()
{
  minim = new Minim(this);
  song40 = minim.loadFile("40.wav");
  song41 = minim.loadFile("41.wav");
  song42 = minim.loadFile("42.wav");
  song43 = minim.loadFile("43.wav");
  song44 = minim.loadFile("44.wav");
  song45 = minim.loadFile("45.wav");
  song46 = minim.loadFile("46.wav");
  song47 = minim.loadFile("47.wav");
  song48 = minim.loadFile("48.wav");
  song49 = minim.loadFile("49.wav");

  String portName = "/dev/cu.usbmodem1411";                             //Change COM48 to the port number that your Arduino is connected, you can check the port number from arduino program.
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 115200);

  size(160, 160);
  background(0);
}

void draw()
{
  if ( myPort.available() > 0 )
  {  // If data is available,
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
    if(val!=null)
    {
      print(val);
      if(val.charAt(0)=='a')
      {
        song40.rewind();
        song40.play();
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(0, 0, 160, 160);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(50);
        text("DO", 80, 90);
      }
      if(val.charAt(0)=='b')
      {
        song41.rewind();
        song41.play();
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(0, 0, 160, 160);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(50);
        text("DO#", 80, 90);
      }
      if(val.charAt(0)=='c')
      {
        song42.rewind();
        song42.play();
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(0, 0, 160, 160);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(50);
        text("RE", 80, 90);
      }
      if(val.charAt(0)=='d')
      {
        song43.rewind();
        song43.play();
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(0, 0, 160, 160);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(50);
        text("RE#", 80, 90);
      }
      if(val.charAt(0)=='e')
      {
        song44.rewind();
        song44.play();
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(0, 0, 160, 160);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(50);
        text("MI", 80, 90);
      }
      if(val.charAt(0)=='f')
      {
        song45.rewind();
        song45.play();
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(0, 0, 160, 160);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(50);
        text("FA", 80, 90);
      }
      if(val.charAt(0)=='g')
      {
        song46.rewind();
        song46.play();
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(0, 0, 160, 160);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(50);
        text("FA#", 80, 90);
      }
      if(val.charAt(0)=='h')
      {
        song47.rewind();
        song47.play();
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(0, 0, 160, 160);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(50);
        text("SOL", 80, 90);
      }
      if(val.charAt(0)=='i')
      {
        song48.rewind();
        song48.play();
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(0, 0, 160, 160);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(50);
        text("SOL#", 80, 90);
      }
      if(val.charAt(0)=='j')
      {
        song49.rewind();
        song49.play();
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(0, 0, 160, 160);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(50);
        text("LA", 80, 90);
      }
    }
  }

  if (mousePressed == true)
  {
    if(r==1)
    {
      myPort.write(' ');
      background(0);
    }
    r=0;
    m=1;
  }
}

public void stop()
{
  minim.stop();
}
```

And here's the Arduino Code:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>

#define total 30                   //define sensitivity, high value for decreases sensitivity, low value increases
#define sensor 1                  //define number of samples Arduino takes, high value will increase stability while increasing response time
#define replay 40                 //define debouncing, high value will increase stability while increasing response time

int led = 13;
int state = HIGH;

boolean yes12;
boolean previous12 = false;

boolean yes11;
boolean previous11 = false;

boolean yes10;
boolean previous10 = false;

boolean yes9;
boolean previous9 = false;

boolean yes8;
boolean previous8 = false;

boolean yes7;
boolean previous7 = false;

boolean yes6;
boolean previous6 = false;

boolean yes5;
boolean previous5 = false;

boolean yes4;
boolean previous4 = false;

boolean yes3;
boolean previous3 = false;

CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_12 = CapacitiveSensor(2,12);        // 2.2M resistor between pins 2 & 12, pin 2 is send pin, pin 12 is sensor pin
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_11 = CapacitiveSensor(2,11);        // 2.2M resistor between pins 2 & 11, pin 2 is send pin, pin 11 is sensor pin
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_10 = CapacitiveSensor(2,10);        // 2.2M resistor between pins 2 & 10, pin 2 is send pin, pin 10 is sensor pin
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_9 = CapacitiveSensor(2,9);
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_8 = CapacitiveSensor(2,8);
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_7 = CapacitiveSensor(2,7);
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_6 = CapacitiveSensor(2,6);
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_5 = CapacitiveSensor(2,5);
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_4 = CapacitiveSensor(2,4);
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_3 = CapacitiveSensor(2,3);

void setup()
{
  cs_2_12.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);  //Calibrate the sensor...
  cs_2_11.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  cs_2_10.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  cs_2_9.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  cs_2_8.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  cs_2_7.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  cs_2_6.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  cs_2_5.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  cs_2_4.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  cs_2_3.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

short int a=1,a1=0,b=1,b1=0,c=1,c1=0,d=1,d1=0,e=1,e1=0,f=1,f1=0,g=1,g1=0,h=1,h1=0,i=1,i1=0,j=1,j1=0;  //for debounce purpose

void loop()
{
  long total112 =  cs_2_12.capacitiveSensor(sensor);
  long total111 =  cs_2_11.capacitiveSensor(sensor);
  long total110 =  cs_2_10.capacitiveSensor(sensor);
  long total19 =  cs_2_9.capacitiveSensor(sensor);
  long total18 =  cs_2_8.capacitiveSensor(sensor);
  long total17 =  cs_2_7.capacitiveSensor(sensor);
  long total16 =  cs_2_6.capacitiveSensor(sensor);
  long total15 =  cs_2_5.capacitiveSensor(sensor);
  long total14 =  cs_2_4.capacitiveSensor(sensor);
  long total13 =  cs_2_3.capacitiveSensor(sensor);

  if (total112 > total){yes12 = true;}
  else {yes12 = false;}

  if (total111 > total){yes11 = true;}
  else {yes11 = false;}

  if (total110 > total){yes10 = true;}
  else {yes10 = false;}

  if (total19 > total){yes9 = true;}
  else {yes9 = false;}

  if (total18 > total){yes8 = true;}
  else {yes8 = false;}

  if (total17 > total){yes7 = true;}
  else {yes7 = false;}

  if (total16 > total){yes6 = true;}
  else {yes6 = false;}

  if (total15 > total){yes5 = true;}
  else {yes5 = false;}

  if (total14 > total){yes4 = true;}
  else {yes4 = false;}

  if (total13 > total){yes3 = true;}
  else {yes3 = false;}

  if(yes12 == true && previous12  == false && a)
  {
      if(state == LOW) {
        state = HIGH;
      }
      else
        state = LOW;
      a = 0;
      a1 = 0;
      Serial.println('a');
  }
  if(yes12 == false && previous12  == false)
    a1++;
  else
    a1=0;
  if(a1==replay)
  {
    a=1;
    a1=0;
  }
  if(yes11 == true && previous11  == false && b)
  {
    if(state == LOW) {
      state = HIGH;
    }
    else
      state = LOW;
    b = 0;
    b1 = 0;
    Serial.println('b');
  }
  if(yes11 == false && previous11  == false)
    b1++;
  else
    b1=0;
  if(b1==replay)
  {
    b=1;
    b1=0;
  }
  if(yes10 == true && previous10  == false && c)
  {
    if(state == LOW){
      state = HIGH;
    }
    else
      state = LOW;
    c = 0;
    c1 = 0;
    Serial.println('c');
  }
  if(yes10== false && previous10  == false)
    c1++;
  else
    c1=0;
  if(c1==replay)
  {
    c=1;
    c1=0;
  }
  if(yes9 == true && previous9  == false && d)
  {
    if(state == LOW){
      state = HIGH;
    }
    else
    state = LOW;
    d = 0;
    d1 = 0;
    Serial.println('d');
  }
  if(yes9== false && previous9  == false)
    d1++;
  else
    d1=0;
  if(d1==replay)
  {
    d=1;
    d1=0;
  }
  if(yes8 == true && previous8  == false && e)
  {
    if(state == LOW){
      state = HIGH;
    }
    else
    state = LOW;
    e = 0;
    e1 = 0;
    Serial.println('e');
  }
  if(yes8== false && previous8  == false)
    e1++;
  else
    e1=0;
  if(e1==replay)
  {
    e=1;
    e1=0;
  }
  if(yes7 == true && previous7  == false && f)
  {
    if(state == LOW){
      state = HIGH;
    }
    else
    state = LOW;
    f = 0;
    f1 = 0;
    Serial.println('f');
  }
  if(yes7== false && previous7  == false)
    f1++;
  else
    f1=0;
  if(f1==replay)
  {
    f=1;
    f1=0;
  }
  if(yes6 == true && previous6  == false && g)
  {
    if(state == LOW){
      state = HIGH;
    }
    else
    state = LOW;
    g = 0;
    g1 = 0;
    Serial.println('g');
  }
  if(yes6== false && previous6  == false)
    g1++;
  else
    g1=0;
  if(g1==replay)
  {
    g=1;
    g1=0;
  }
  if(yes5 == true && previous5  == false && h)
  {
    if(state == LOW){
      state = HIGH;
    }
    else
    state = LOW;
    h = 0;
    h1 = 0;
    Serial.println('h');
  }
  if(yes5== false && previous5  == false)
    h1++;
  else
    h1=0;
  if(h1==replay)
  {
    h=1;
    h1=0;
  }
  if(yes4 == true && previous4  == false && i)
  {
    if(state == LOW){
      state = HIGH;
    }
    else
    state = LOW;
    i = 0;
    i1 = 0;
    Serial.println('i');
  }
  if(yes4== false && previous4  == false)
    i1++;
  else
    i1=0;
  if(i1==replay)
  {
    i=1;
    i1=0;
  }
  if(yes3 == true && previous3  == false && j)
  {
    if(state == LOW){
      state = HIGH;
    }
    else
    state = LOW;
    j = 0;
    j1 = 0;
    Serial.println('j');
  }
  if(yes3== false && previous3  == false)
  j1++;
  else
  j1=0;
  if(j1==replay)
  {
    j=1;
    j1=0;
  }

  digitalWrite(led, state);
  previous12 = yes12;
  previous11 = yes11;
  previous10 = yes10;
  previous9 = yes9;
  previous8 = yes8;
  previous7 = yes7;
  previous6 = yes6;
  previous5 = yes5;
  previous4 = yes4;
  previous3 = yes3;

  delay(2);
}
```

Thank you in Advance. :)

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit it into your question in place of the pages of code.

Comment: No need to apologise - I'm just trying to help you get help. It's not about the formatting (although it's good that it's properly formatted now) but about allowing people to focus on the problem. If you read the MCVE article I linked, you'll get a better understanding.

Comment: Even more reason to break it down to a minimal example ☺️ The exercise will help you understand it☺️

Comment: The diagram looks wrong. Why are there two 10Mohm resistors?

Comment: @gerben It was an error with my fritzing app. All the resistors have a value of 10Mohm not just two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### About your actual question

You have to realize that you are trying to measure **tiny**
capacitances, which is not completely trivial. Detecting your finger
“from at least a few inches away” is probably impossible with this
setup, as we are talking about fractions of a picofarad.

There are a few things you can do to increase the sensitivity though:

- make sure both you and the Arduino are properly grounded
- make the pads as big as practically possible
- increase the series resistance
- lower the detection threshold (your `total` constant) until you are at
  the verge of seeing spurious detections.

### About your Arduino code

This is not directly related to your question, but it addresses the
criticism you received for posting too large a program.

Looking at your code, it appears to be quite simple. It is too big only
because almost every statement is repeated ten times (once per piano
key). The simple thing you could have done is to remove all but one (or
maybe two) keys. This would have made the program easily digestible for
anyone trying to help you. What I strongly recommend is that you learn
about **using loops and arrays** in C++. This will allow you to avoid
repetition by instead looping through the arrays. Here is for example
how you could rewrite your `setup()` function based on an array of
sensors:

```
const size_t SENSOR_COUNT = 10;

CapacitiveSensor sensors[SENSOR_COUNT] = {
    CapacitiveSensor(2, 12),
    CapacitiveSensor(2, 11),
    CapacitiveSensor(2, 10),
    CapacitiveSensor(2, 9),
    CapacitiveSensor(2, 8),
    CapacitiveSensor(2, 7),
    CapacitiveSensor(2, 6),
    CapacitiveSensor(2, 5),
    CapacitiveSensor(2, 4),
    CapacitiveSensor(2, 3)
};

void setup()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SENSOR_COUNT; i++)
        sensors[i].set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(-1);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(115200);
}
```

As you can see here, the sensor initialization
(`set_CS_AutocaL_Millis()`) is only written once, and the Arduino is
instructed by the `for` loop to repeat the same thing on every sensor,
one after the other. If you then do the same for `loop()`, you will end
up with a program that is almost ten times shorter, and a *whole lot*
easier to read, modify and debug. For that, you would need to also
replace your `yesXX`, `previousXX`, `a`, `a1`, `b`, `b1`, `c`, `c1`...
variables with arrays.

At this point you have a collection of arrays. The next level in
modularization is to replace the collection of arrays by an array of
collections: you put all the data relevant to one piano key inside an
object, and then you have just one array of such objects.

I tried rewriting your program with this approach, and I am posting the
result here. Beware that I did not test it. I realize this may be a
little bit above your current level, but I hope it will at least give
you an idea of how the language allows you to abstract things: the whole
logic about detecting whether a key was hit lives in the
`PianoKey::hit()` method, and then the `loop()` becomes short and
simple.

```
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>

class PianoKey : private CapacitiveSensor
{
    public:
        PianoKey(byte sendPin, byte receivePin, char _note)
            : CapacitiveSensor(sendPin, receivePin), note(_note),
              last_state(false), last_toggle(0)
            { set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(-1); }
        bool hit();
        char note;
    private:
        static const byte SAMPLES = 1;     // number of samples to average
        static const long THRESHOLD = 30;  // detection threshold
        static const short DEBOUNCE = 50;  // debounce time (ms)
        bool last_state;
        uint32_t last_toggle;
};

// Returns true once per hit on the key.
bool PianoKey::hit()
{
    uint32_t now = millis();
    if (now - last_toggle < DEBOUNCE)
        return false;
    bool state = capacitiveSensor(SAMPLES) > THRESHOLD;
    bool was_hit = state && !last_state;
    if (state != last_state) {
        last_state = state;
        last_toggle = now;
    }
    return was_hit;
}

const size_t KEY_COUNT = 10;

PianoKey keys[KEY_COUNT] = {
    PianoKey(2, 12, 'a'),
    PianoKey(2, 11, 'b'),
    PianoKey(2, 10, 'c'),
    PianoKey(2,  9, 'd'),
    PianoKey(2,  8, 'e'),
    PianoKey(2,  7, 'f'),
    PianoKey(2,  6, 'g'),
    PianoKey(2,  5, 'h'),
    PianoKey(2,  4, 'i'),
    PianoKey(2,  3, 'j'),
};

void setup()
{
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
    static int led_state = HIGH;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < KEY_COUNT; i++) {
        if (keys[i].hit()) {
            led_state = !led_state;  // toggle LED
            Serial.println(keys[i].note);
        }
    }
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, led_state);
}
```

A couple of final notes:

- The line `class PianoKey : private CapacitiveSensor` says a piano key
  *is* a capacitive sensor with some extra functionality. Another valid
  option would be to say that the key *has* a sensor, i.e. to store a
  `CapacitiveSensor` inside the object.
- <s>I do not know whether it's safe to call `set_CS_AutocaL_Millis()`
  before the low-level initialization of the Arduino. That's why it's
  done in a `begin()` method to be called by `setup()`.</s> I checked
  the source code of the CapacitiveSensor library, and it appears that
  `set_CS_AutocaL_Millis()` does nothing but set a private member of the
  object. This means it is safe to call it from a global constructor,
  before the hardware initialization of the Arduino.
  Had this not been the case, one would need to defer this call until
  `setup()`, as done in [a previous version of this
  answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/revisions/34677/2).
- The `PianoKey::hit()` method uses time-based rather than
  loop-count-based debouncing. This should be more consistent if you
  change the program in a manner that changes the time it takes to loop.
  It does pure debouncing: you may want to change that to an algorithm
  that combines debouncing with deglitching.

Answer (score 2):

Cap sensing is quite sensitive to the sense pad design. Generally you want thee pad to sufficiently big. I haven't seen a single wire design as you are using here.

I would play with one wire first and adjust your code to make it work before taking on more pads.